# Getting web links to all items in a table and then doing pagination

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am able to get all the links on a particular web page but am having trouble with the pagination.
I am doing the following:

```
import requests, bs4, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

r = requests.get(start_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
a_tags = soup.find_all('a')
print(a_tags)
links = [urljoin(start_url, a['href'])for a in a_tags]
print(links)
```

As a toy example, I am using the following website:

`start_url = 'https://www.opencodez.com/page/1'`

I am able to get all the links this way. However, I am trying to automate it more by going to the next page and doing the same thing, and outputting all the links to a csv file.

I tried the following but get no outputs:

```
start_url = 'https://www.opencodez.com/'

with open('names.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
   fieldnames = ['Name']
   writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
   writer.writeheader()

article_link = []
def scraping(webpage, page_number):
    next_page = webpage + str(page_number)
    r = requests.get(str(next_page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
    a_tags = soup.find_all('a')
    print(a_tags)
    links = [urljoin(start_url, a['href'])for a in a_tags]
    print(links)
    for x in range(len(soup)):
      article_link.append(links)

    if page_number < 16:
     page_number = page_number + 1
     scraping(webpage, page_number)
    scraping('https://www.opencodez.com/page/', 1)

   #creating the data frame and populating its data into the csv file
data = { 'Name': article_link}
df = DataFrame(data, columns = ['Article_Link'])
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\xxxxx\names.csv')
```

Could you please help me determine where I am going wrong?
I do not mind getting the links in either the output console or printed in a csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were issues here and there with your code but this worked for me:

```py
import requests, bs4, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

start_url = 'https://www.opencodez.com/'
r = requests.get(start_url)                      # first page scraping
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
a_tags = soup.find_all('a')

article_link = []

links = [urljoin(start_url, a['href'])for a in a_tags]
article_link.append(links)

for page in range(2,19):              # for every page after 1
    links = []                          # resetting lists on every page just in case
    a_tags = []                 
    url = 'https://www.opencodez.com/page/'+str(page)
    r = requests.get(start_url)                    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
    a_tags = soup.find_all('a')
    links = [urljoin(start_url, a['href'])for a in a_tags]

    article_link.append(links)

print(article_link)
```

I basically just changed how you append to the list `article_link`. This variable at the moment is a list of length 18. Each list within `article_link` is a list of 136 links.

Comment: When I print it, I am getting the same 136 links, 18 times. It is not paginating

Comment: I think it should be r = requests.get(url) within the pagination loop